# Synchronize local server and production server

Tags: php, production-environment, synchronize, localserver

I am doing a PHP project which is almost completed and uploaded to Production server for Client demo. Since The client is specifying some  changes. I am doing that changes in my local server and later upload it to production server. Since some changes will took in more that 1 files its really difficult me to update the Production server via FTP.

Is there any way to Synchronize the changes made in local server with production server??

Is there any way to configure SVN in production server???

please help

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i think that you have your own answer... SVN... what you need is a [SVN server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69384/opinion-of-hosted-svn-providers).. (maybe in the same Production server or not), and if you have ssh access to your production server all you need to do is login in a console and update the new version.. for that you'd have to learn the [basic svn commands](http://wiki.greenstone.org/wiki/index.php/Useful_SVN_Commands), so you wont override configuration files or upload/download files you dont need (like uploaded images, etc)...

good luck!

Comment: now i have a local SVN server. How can i export it into remote production server?? whether the export will overwrite whole files in remote server with the files in repo??  how can i export only the latest changes into remote production server??

Comment: your production server needs to have access to the SVN server. Then just connect to your prod server via ssh, or via console and do a ´svn checkout´ the first time. It will copy the entire project to your prod serv, now every time you want to update the prod server you can do a ´svn update´. I forgot to tell you that your prod server needs a SVN client. Search on the web for good tutorials like this one:
http://pointbeing.net/weblog/2009/03/command-line-subversion-tutorial-part-1.html

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do a 'checkout' of your project to the server? I think that would be the simplest thing to do.

When you change something in your system you just commit and then update in the production server. Either that or do a scp or rsync.